# Random crashes on COCOS2dx game android

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x

Android NDK error while running application find this error in logcat.

```
 Build fingerprint: 'i1017/i1017/i1017:4.1.1/JRO03H/20130601.100904:eng/release-keys'
        pid: 1981, tid: 1990, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> com.verve.rummy <<<
        signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
        Stack frame #00  pc 00013778  /system/lib/libc.so
        Stack frame #01  pc 00015b55  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+1628)
        Stack frame #02  pc 00016d03  /system/lib/libc.so (free+10)
        Stack frame #03  pc 0001de30  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
        Stack frame #04  pc 0004d083  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+394)
        Stack frame #05  pc 00027260  /system/lib/libdvm.so
        Stack frame #06  pc 0002bb68  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
        Stack frame #07  pc 0005f7f1  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
        Stack frame #08  pc 0005f81b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
        Stack frame #09  pc 000543d3  /system/lib/libdvm.so
        Stack frame #10  pc 00012b70  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
        Stack frame #11  pc 000122c8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
```

I am getting this type of error in stack while running my android game.
Above i put my error log please help me for resolve this error.
Due to this my game crashes randomly.

I am using android NDK for build application

Sorry for my poor English.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't shown any code, how can we possibly diagnose this?

Comment: This is issue related to NDK build and cocos2d. While passing message via JNI this error occured not due to code because in error there nothing specified that due to this code you have error.

Comment: `fault addr deadbaad`  you are trying to access deleted (but not NULL) pointer.